# Agregar un color de fondo a celdas con POI en java

Tags: java, apache-poi

Al abrir un excel (xls - formato 2003) que contiene números debo recorrer todas las hojas y quiero que en las celdas me agregue un color de fondo (debo agregarle un color de fondo a determinadas celdas, elimine esa lógica por no ser relevante al problema) y grabarlo en otro archivo.

Estoy usando la versión POI 3.12 y java 6

```
FileInputStream fsIP= new FileInputStream(new File("ejemplo.xls"));
HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(fsIP);

for (int i = 0; i < wb.getNumberOfSheets(); i++) {
    HSSFSheet hoja = wb.getSheetAt(i);

    for (Row fila: hoja) {
        for (Cell celda : fila) {
            CellStyle estilo = celda.getCellStyle();
            estilo.setLocked(false);
            estilo.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.GREEN.getIndex());
            celda.setCellStyle(estilo);
        }
    }
}

fsIP.close();
FileOutputStream outputFile =new FileOutputStream("nuevo.xls");
wb.write(outputFile);
outputFile.close();
```

El problema es que me cambia solamente las celdas que ya tienen un color de fondo, las que estan en blanco siguen en blanco.

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo pude solucionar con

```
estilo.setFillPattern((short) 1);
```

Comment: Hola, me enfrento al mismo problema pero no pude replicar tu solución como lo llegaste a hacer?